# Django model's attribute to dynamic change default value of ImageField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class ImageTest(models.Model):
    pic = models.ForeignKey(Pic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_field = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=' << HERE I WANT TO CHANGE DYNAMIC >>')
```

When adding a ImageTest Object, I select a pic from my existing Pic objects. But then, I want to auto-complete the image_field with a image from path that corresponds to the Pic object.

For example:

- If I choose the Pic Object #1 (foreign key) -> my path for imageField to be: images/pic1.jpg
- If I choose the Pic Object #2 -> my path to be images/pic2.jpg 
  and so on.

How can I make this to be done the moment I choose the Pic object, not when pressing Save button?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure setting the default here is the right way to go. I don't think you can change the default value without migrating the database.
Instead, I'd maybe override the `save()` method of the `ImageTest` model to set the `image_field` based on the `pic` value.

Something like this maybe:

```
class ImageTest(models.Model):
    pic = models.ForeignKey(Pic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_field = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pic:
            self.image_field = self.pic.image_path # whatever the corresponding pic field is
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also implement the save() method so the `image_field` only gets set when the `ImageTest` is being created by checking for `pk` as this will not be set until `super().save()` is called.

```
if not self.pk and self.pk:
    self.image_field = self.pic.image_path # whatever the corresponding pic field is
```

Comment: Yea, I thought about this way, but I need that image_field to be set when I choose the pic and this doesn't solve my problem. LE: I am thinking about another option: What if after selecting the Pic, I run the save method and refresh the page, so the image_field also gets completed with what I need. PS: I need that image_field because I use CropperJS on that image_filed to select only a part of the uploaded image.

Comment: This does not help ben bulk_saving this model,as `save()` won't get called then, and neither when migrating the model or creating a migration (which does Django). It will produce an error then.